# Does SDL2 prebuilt windows dll-s have directx or opengl support compiled in?

Tags: windows, opengl, directx, sdl-2

I have downloaded the prebuilt windows dll-s from here: https://www.libsdl.org/download-2.0.php, but I am not able to get hardware accelerated renderer working.

Does they include directx or opengl support?
Or shall I compile my own if I want hardware accelerated video?

I do cross-compile my app with linux/cmake/mingw at the moment and linking with prebuild SDL2 dll-s.

Comment: Iterate over available drivers using SDL_GetNumRenderDrivers() -> SDL_CreateRenderer() -> SDL_GetRendererInfo() ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They have directx support built in.

Mingw can link to those libraries.

(Did not work for me with Virtualbox, but did work with native windows.)